# Moving Text Freely Inside Its parent

Tags: css, pixel

I'm New to CSS.

Is there a way to move text within the following **span** like a non-repeated **background-image**?

for example: 50px from left, 40 px from left? without causing extra height and width!

```
div{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

<body>
<div>
<span>Hello World</span>
</div>
</body>
```

Can I ask more question? how many space does a 16px character occupies? I mean what does 16px mean? 16pixel wide? 16 pixel height? when we select a character with mouse, there is a blue box around the selected character, which is bigger than that character. is this relevant to this question?

Comment: Sorry, how can I make the text, center left , center center, center right from DIV?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I think `font-size` always relates to the height of the letters and the reason the "blue box" is slightly larger is because it is highlighting the line specified by `line-height`.

To position the text inside your box you have a couple of options:

1) You can absolutely position the `span` inside the `div` like so:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xukp/

2) You can set the `span`'s `display` to `block` or `inline-block` and then apply `margin` or `padding` to position the `span` like so:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m79as/

**EDIT** - In response to your comment, there is no property like `background-position` where you can set it to be `center center` or `center left` however you can use `vertical-align` and `text-align` to position the text. In order to vertically align the `span` correctly you will need to set the `display` to `table-cell`

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center; /* left|right|center|justify */
    vertical-align: middle; /* top|text-top|middle|bottom|text-bottom */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ExB2/